# Passing variable from main to Async class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, global-variables

Somehow, I can't get this done. This is all what I tried till now:

1. **Main**:

   ```
   private String myState;

   public String getState() {
       return myState;
   }

   public void setState(String s) {
       myState = s;
   }
   ```

   **Async**:

   ```
   Main appState = ((Main)getApplicationContext());
   String state = appState.getState();
   ```

   Error:  `No enclosing instance of the type Main is accessible in scope`
2. Tried with Helper(Globals) class.

   ```
   public class Globals extends Application{
         private String test= "1";
   }
   ```

   **Main**:

   ```
   private Globals mGlobals;
   mGlobals = new Globals();  
   mGlobals.test = "2";
   //Do Async thing
   ```

   **Async**:

   ```
   private Globals mGlobals;
   mGlobals = new Globals();
   print mGlobals.test;
   // (result is 1, should be 2)
   ```
3. Also something else, but don't remember good.
   Tried alot of things (backspace and del buttons are over-used :p )
   But I can't get everything working.

   Async class doesn't have an activity.

Code pasted: http://pastebin.com/ikcsdL1p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to get Application Context , try to pass Context directly in AsyncTask Constructor. as @Mohd Mufiz already mentioned in his Answer.

Comment: I tried, but I can't get it to work somehow, I probably do still something wrong, going to post full code soon. I think I just missing a little thing here.

Comment: You didn't use your constructor to get the context from Activity.

Comment: Ah! Shoot, I did (but deleted it again), but I also did it wrong the first time I see. Now I get it :), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Declare a constructor in your async class like

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>

{

private Context context;

        public Task(Context context)
        {
         this.context=context;
        }    
}
```

And from your main class

```
new Task(this).execute((Void)null);
```

Comment: Sorry, can't get this to work. Can't I just use an other class for it.  
In C++ this was so much easier...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ikcsdL1p posted my code here, I deleted what I tried. Could you make thatr code fit, then I can see what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SharedPreferences... To create and call String var use ...

```
String button_name_11 = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("butname11", "EMPTY");
```

And then to change, just ...

```
getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putString("butname11", "NEW_STRING" )
                .commit();
```

Comment: `getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("butname11", "EMPTY"));` Error:`MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable`  Probably because it doesn't have an Activity

Comment: Try to use Context.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("butname11", "EMPTY"));